# Check if bash script (run by cron job) is running in Openshift

Tags: linux, bash, cron, openshift, redhat

I try `ps aux` and `ps` and `pgrep myprocess` and `pidof myprocess` but all say my script is not running (while my script is actually running). I check these command with ssh.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you use ssh to have to watch the pid you are actually sending

So run pgrep like this, ssh returns the exit status from the command you run:

```
ssh myserver 'pgrep -u username scriptname' 
[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'Running' || echo "Not running"
```

username is the name of the user that started the process ex: root, daniyal, santa, or maybe jim
scriptname the actual name of the script file ex: myscript.sh, fixit.sh, or maybe foo.sh

Comment: I type ssh myserver then log in, Then in terminal of myserver type `'pgrep -u username scriptname'` and nothing in output (`[ $? -eq 0 ] && echo 'Running' || echo "Not running"
` return Not running).Any other idea?, Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the username.  what is the real name of the script? it sounds like you are very confused.

Comment: @jimmcnamara He is not confused at all, I've found the same behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867553/openshift-manage-cron-processes , currently, openshift runs your cron scripts with your own user, but (maybe by misconfiguration) you are not allowed to see this cron processes via ps or even access the process pid. The user running this cron scripts is the same you use in your session, is a mistery to me you have no rights to see them.