# Openshift: manage cron processes

Tags: php, ssh, cron, openshift

I've setup my project and a cron file inside an openshift box, the project runs ok, but for some reason I can't manage cron running processes, I can't even list them, if I connect via ssh and exec 'ps aux' the cron process doesnt even appear.

I write a little test:

```
<?php
    file_put_contents('../../b.log','pid: '.getmypid().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents('../../b.log',shell_exec('whoami'),FILE_APPEND);
```

cat b.log:

```
pid: 194061
54ae4f424382ec439100xxxx //the user is right, the cron process is running behind the same user
```

whoami from ssh spits the same user, but if I try to reach the process I get:

```
ls /proc/194061
ls: no se puede acceder a /proc/194061: Permiso denegado //Permission denied
```

the process exists because /proc/19406[TAB] completes and I see the log files populating but I cant check if the process is really running or not via ssh or via web :S

Answer (score 0):

Cron processes only run for a short time and then stop, they do not run continuously.  If your cron process updates the file correctly, then it ran correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I know, the current time limit is 20m, take my example like if a sleep(600); was after the file_put_contents. I posted a bug in openshift bugzilla that has been accepted. There is no posibility to comunicate cron processes cause cron is running on other privilege level (I supose) and you will never know when a cron process is running or not because you cant list them with ps aux or open /proc/[pid] (in case you log this pid to a file for example)